# VSCode colours are changing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Okay. I recently noticed that the colouring of my VSCode has been doing weird stuff.

When I have opened the program everything seems find, then after a few seconds the colours go different; https://gyazo.com/24efddee7634daec957f84d03888fe0a - You can see at the end that the colours are changing.

I obsolutely cannot code like this, really my OCD is going completely nuts. It currently looks like this (after changing); 
[image: VSCode]

I really need this fixed.

Comment: It's just that your editor is taking a while to recognize that console is already a preset variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677079/vs-code-javascript-syntax-highlighting#60677079  Try "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted, it seems as though VSCode is simply greying out the variables you're not using. This is pretty standard behaviour in any code editor.

Comment: It's not the variables changing, it's how require is usually yellow, console.log is usually green, and now they are blue.